# Pivot Table Value Adjustments

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table from multiple tables. When I double-click my pivot table data, it produces a copy of the row(s) that data came from. Is there a way for me to make adjustments aka change the values of cells in these rows, and have it only adjust the pivot table?

What I'm mainly looking for is an easy way of viewing the data through the pivot table, and adjusting it without it necessarily affecting the source tables. Right now when I adjust a row produced by the pivot table, none of the values in the actual pivot table get updated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about producing a new PivotTable from the drilldown sheet that got produced when you double-clicked the old PivotTable?

That's about as close as you're going to get, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The pivot table is a visualization tool only. It summarizes that data that you input into the pivot table, and gives you a visual output.

If you want to change that visual output, you have to copy the relevant part of the pivot table to another area (different cell or sheet, doesn't matter). Then, you can edit that table.